# How to hide specific text from content wihtout calling any CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide only word "QUICK" from the content below without calling any class or changes in Markup. It is not possible in pure CSS, probably we can do this JavaScript / jQuery and call QUICK as a variable and use CSS to hide. I am not good in Java coding so can anyone help this around?

Example:

```
<html>
<p>The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>The quick brown fox is too hungry.</p>
<p>The poor quick brown fox is tired and thirsty.</p>
</html>
```

Please provide solution in JSFiddle, if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find all occurences of `quick` and wrap them intp a specific element (e.g. `<del>`) hidden via css

CSS

```
p del {
   display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('p').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.html($this.text().replace(/\bquick\b/g, '<del>quick</del>'));
});
```

Example jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ogakit/1/

Comment: Nice shot, you even respected document semantic by placing deleted elements in a <del> markup. Bravo i fiddled it for you : http://jsfiddle.net/jLu7h/1/

Comment: Sorry not working, please check http://jsfiddle.net/5MWfD/
Basically i don't want to change anything in HTML Markup. JavaScript function should search all over and hide/delete the word 'quick' automatically without calling any references.

Answer (score 1):

see the fiddle [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLu7h/2/) now its working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('p').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
   $this.html($this.text().replace(/\bquick\b/g, '<span style="display:none">quick</span>'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome and if done mark it as answer that somebody else see can identify

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want ..!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body id ="demo">

<p>The quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>The quick brown fox is too hungry.</p>
<p>The poor quick brown fox is tired and thirsty.</p>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var str=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace("quick","HIDDEN");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```