# How to hide special characters without calling on specific css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically need to hide #hashtag every time it appears in a paragraph.
I'm halfway there with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361542/how-to-hide-specific-text-from-content-wihtout-calling-any-css).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('p').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.text().replace(/\bquick\b/g, '<span style="display:none">quick</span>'));
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLu7h/2)

It seems the # is effecting it.
Any ideas, Thanks!

**Update:**

Thanks, all good working examples.

This brings me to my next problem, it seems to be messing with my font-awesome on my site. As well as break tags.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhdm9f54/)

Comment: Can you give sample input and sample out? Your JSFiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the '# is affecting it' as your jsfiddle doesn't include a # and when it's added, it works fine.

Comment: @osc_jackson - You should accept the working example as an answer since it answers your FIRST initial question.. the second problem should be a new question

Answer (score 1):

By changing the regex to `/#hashtag/g` of existing code, you have same functionality to hide `#hashtag` within paragraphs

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oczy6vp8/1/)

Comment: You might prefer this regex:  /\s*#\w+/g

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) DOM insertion and replace the `#` character with blank using regex:

```
$("p").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/(#)/g, '');
});
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwfc5407/)**